# plt.imsave does not work when alpha channel is added

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I want to write a PNG image with transparent background.
When I add an alpha channel to the array. [plt.imsave](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) will not work. Let red, green, blue be numpy arrays as type float32.

Works:

```
mask = red*green*blue
red[np.where(mask==0)]=0
green[np.where(mask==0)]=0
blue[np.where(mask==0)]=0

rgb = np.dstack((red,green,blue))
plt.imsave("sample.png", rgb, dpi = 300)
```

Does Not Work:

```
mask = red*green*blue
red[np.where(mask==0)]=0
green[np.where(mask==0)]=0
blue[np.where(mask==0)]=0
alpha = np.where((mask==0), 0, 255).astype('float32')
rgba = np.dstack((red,green,blue, alpha))
plt.imsave("sample.png", rgba, dpi = 300)
```

plt.imsave just stop working when I add an alpha channel. How to resolve this?

Comment: you tagged `opencv`, why not use `cv2.imwrite()`?

Comment: I tried it but the output is a full alpha channel, or just a transparent image. It does not return error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't look right:

```
alpha = np.where((mask==0), 0, 255).astype('float32')
```

Shouldn't it be either:

```
alpha = np.where((mask==0), 0, 1).astype('float32')
```

or

```
alpha = np.where((mask==0), 0, 255).astype('uint8')
```

depending on `dtype` of `rgb` channels.